# Организация доступа к БД в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, php, клиент-сервер, html, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Имеются аудитория с 15ю компьютерами - рабочие - и комната с 1м компьютером - главным. Все соединено в лок.сеть.

Нужно разработать интерфейс для работы с БД, расположенной на главном. К примеру на Рабочем столе рабочего компьютера лежит html-файл, при запуске которого отправляется запрос на главный, и отображается интерфейс взаимодействия с БД. Для разработки БД и интерфейса я взял MySQL и PHP соответственно. На сколько я понял так же необходим сервер Apache, установленный на главном.

Каким образом рабочие компьютеры могут взаимодействовать с БД на главном? Понятно, что через браузер, и обращаться по ip-адресу к главному, но как это будет выглядеть в коде на php? И как узнать ip-адрес главного компьютера в лок.сети?

Спасибо.

Comment: На главном какая операционка стоит?

Comment: Windows Xp SP3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставите linux apache php mysql phpmyadmin (для визуальной работы с базой).

Настраиваете apache, открываете 80 порт у главного компа.
ip можно узнать через `iwconfig || ifconfig` (команды в bash).

Если нужен просто доступ к базе, то этого хватит!

Если нужен интерфейс, то тогда берите книгу по php+mysql+js+html+css и читайте.